# Cocoapod install does not add to PATH

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

I installed cocoapods on OSX 10.9.3 Mavericks.

The installation finished fine, but I cannot run the pod update command. as nothing was added to my PATH. I am trying to find the /usr/local/Cellar/ruby folder to find the pod file to put in my PATH, but no such folder exists.

Where is the cocoapod file installed, and what I need to add in my PATH to make it work?

Comment: How did you install cocoapods? The recommended way on [their homepage](http://cocoapods.org/) is with `gem install`. Installing this way should have made the `pod` command available (installing in /usr/bin).

Comment: Yes I was using sudo to install, but I already had a local ruby rvm installed. this worked:

 gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoapods is installed using Ruby Gems. If you do not have a previous Ruby installation, you can go ahead and install using SUDO, which will use the OSX system default Ruby installation. But if you have a local version of Ruby already running for whatever reason, using SUDO will not work as the pod binary will be installed in the System default Ruby folder instead of the local version where it should be really installed for all the PATH and environment variable to work correctly. Just using gem install should work in this case.

If you have a local version of ruby rvm

`gem install cocoapods`

instead of

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: This is correct. Consider adding a bit of an explanation for the benefit of other developers who will read this answer in the future?